# ImportError while installing ROS2 from source

Tags: ros, ros2, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instructions for installing ROS2 from source (from [github wiki](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup)).

Isolated and non-isolated build:

`src/ament/ament_tools/scripts/ament.py build --build-tests --symlink-install <--isolated>`: I'm getting a `Import Error: No module named 'catkin_pkg'` and a `NameError: name 'catkin_pkg' is not defined`.
The errors occur at **line number 34 and 48** in `ros1_bridge/__init__.py`.

`$ <path-to-python> -c 'import catkin_pkg'` reproduces this error.

Any ideas why? Is there a step that I've missed? Should there be a `sudo -H pip install catkin_pkg rospkg` somewhere in the docs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276862/importerror-while-installing-ros2-from-source/) by [kunaltyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18850/kunaltyagi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2017-11-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-29**:
I would really suggest you report this at the ROS2 github issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the `ros1_bridge` package depends on a number of ROS 1 packages. These are not listed in the main ROS 2 installation instructions that you linked to, but in the ros1_bridge-specific instructions at: https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/blob/master/README.md

Note that there is a particular order in which ROS 1 and ROS 2 workspaces need to be sourced, so you'll need to pay close attention to the steps in the instructions when building from source.

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1